# Dell Studio 1747 doesn't come back from hibernate

Tags: 11.04, dell, hibernate

I installed **Ubuntu 11.04** today and after the first hibernation my **Dell Studio 1747** only wakes up to a blank display. I don't see anything, not even the mouse pointer and can't switch to a console.

Are there any known bugs with the *dell chipsets*, the *ATI graphics* or the *broadcom wireless* card? (I installed the 3rd party drivers for ATI and broadcom.)

**Update**

I chose to encrypt my personal data. I created a swap partition on my 2nd hard drive (the first where Ubuntu is installed is an SSD), but I'm not sure if that swap is in use.

**swapon -s**

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-0               partition   10239996    460 -1
/dev/dm-1               partition   4179964 0   -2
```

**free -m**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3952       3915         36          0       1137        481
-/+ buffers/cache:       2296       1656
Swap:        14081          0      14081
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sdb1              52G  3,7G   45G   8% /
none                  2,0G  708K  2,0G   1% /dev
none                  2,0G  596K  2,0G   1% /dev/shm
none                  2,0G   92K  2,0G   1% /var/run
none                  2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /var/lock
/home/username/.Private
                       52G  3,7G   45G   8% /home/username
/dev/sda2             456G  135G  321G  30% /media/DATA
```

Comment: Same with my Dell Latitude D620 (laptop) :p It just seems to have lost contact with the hard disk.

Comment: I switched back to Debian a few days ago and tonight my laptop went to sleep - and came back when I switched it on this morning. Debian FTW! ;-) Can't say how long it took, because I didn't pay attention to it. But the display was there about 10 minutes later.

Comment: 10 minutes to wake up? O.o Then why would you use hibernate? Much quicker to just boot it up.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. But 10min was only the time I was away, actually it's faster and _only_ takes the display about 1min to come back from sleep.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).